# Updated query resulted in multiple table update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I ran an update query in SQL Server:

```
update benefitplandetails 
set memberterminationage=150
where benefitid = 1 
and planid in (select planid 
               from division 
               where divisionid not in (64, 65))
```

Before that I ran a select command with the same where condition and it resulted in 14 rows. But when I ran the update query with the same `where` condition, it returned multiple results.

The result was something like this :

```
924 rows affected 
0 rows affected
14 rows affected
```

Now I don't have any idea why a single update query resulted in multiple updates and how do I get to know which tables got affected.

I also checked the table had a trigger.

Comment: Triggers. Also mysql <> sql-server so if this is a sql-server question please remove the mysql tag.

Comment: Can you please share your query?

Comment: update benefitplandetails where benefitid=1 and planid in (select planid from division where divisionid not in (64,65))

Comment: can anyone please explain what's wrong and Jacob H i also checked the table had a trigger but didn't understand completely.

Comment: When you run the update against the table, the trigger is also firing. So the 924 updated rows are from the trigger, and the 14 rows are the 14 you are expecting. If you look at the trigger code, it will probably make more sense to you. Nothing is "wrong"--everything appears to be working as implemented in your database.

Comment: I did look at the procedure but couldn't find the impacted table. Also now i cant access the table altogether, query runs for some time and then times out. I can open the table with 'WITH (NOLOCK)' only

Comment: so please summarize: does it have a trigger > if yes, post trigger code; is there a `SET` clause in your update statement, currently in your comment it looks like its truncated.

Comment: there is no set clause in my update query i just want to know how can i look for the impacted table.

Comment: An update is not valid without a set

Comment: ohh sorry yes there is a SET clause i forgot to mention : update benefitplandetails set memberage=150  where benefitid=1 and planid in (select planid from division where divisionid not in (64,65))